# using xmlSerializer.Deserialize to read a string

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm creating a program to read to SVN to see what files have changed in each commit.

I've got the program getting the data and storing it into a string. What I now need to do is to analyze the data. I do not want to create an xml file as I've done it before. I'm unsure how to analyze the data this is may code where it's reading an xml file.

```
private void Show_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fileStream = null;
    fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_filePath, @"svn.log"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);


    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(log));
    log logInstance;
    lock (xmlSerializer)
    {
        logInstance = (log)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
    }
    _dictionary = CreateDictionary(logInstance);
    converToText(_dictionary);
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? On which particular point are you stuck? Do you get an error?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the string to be passed into the xmlSerializer.Deserialize. I have all the data in a string and i want that string to read the string and display the output. Previously I've had it as an xml file but have changed it to have the data in a string as the way the xml file was created made it difficult to run on a new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple `StringReader` for this:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(log));
log logInstance;

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(myXmlString))
{
    logInstance = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Which reads from a `string` instead of a file.